# Extract Outer Text with Scrappy

Tags: python, python-2.7, parsing, xpath, scrapy

I need to parse following fragment:

```
<span>    Lekhwiya&nbsp;v&nbsp;<strong class="winner-strong">Zobahan</strong></span>
```

or

```
<span>    <strong class="winner-strong">Sepahan</strong>&nbsp;v&nbsp;Al&nbsp;Nasr&nbsp;(UAE)</span>
```

as `Lekhwiya v Zobahan` and <`Sepahan v Al' Nasr'(UAE)` properly.

I was trying to parse as:

```
team_1 = block.xpath('.//span/text()').extract()[:2]
team_1 = team_1[0].strip() + team_1[1].strip() 
team_2 = block.xpath('.//span/strong/text()').extract()[0]

item['match'] = team_2.strip() + ' ' + team_1 if team_1[0] == 'v' else team_1 + ' ' + team_2.strip()
```

As for me, it's ugly solution. What is the best approach to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use XPath's string() function, or `normalize-space()` even:

```
In [1]: text = '''
   ...: <span>    Lekhwiya&nbsp;v&nbsp;<strong class="winner-strong">Zobahan</strong></span>
   ...: <span>    <strong class="winner-strong">Sepahan</strong>&nbsp;v&nbsp;Al&nbsp;Nasr&nbsp;(UAE)</span>
   ...: '''

In [2]: import scrapy

In [3]: selector = scrapy.Selector(text=text, type="html")

In [4]: for span in selector.xpath('//span'):
   ...:     print(span.xpath('string(.)').extract_first())
   ...:     
    Lekhwiya v Zobahan
    Sepahan v Al Nasr (UAE)

In [5]: for span in selector.xpath('//span'):
    print(span.xpath('normalize-space(.)').extract_first())
   ...:     
Lekhwiya v Zobahan
Sepahan v Al Nasr (UAE)
```